# How to preserve formatting when sdiff output is sent to a file?

Tags: bash, scripting, sdiff

**Ubuntu 16.04

Bash 4.4.0

sdiff (GNU diffutils) 3.3**

When I use the command sdiff in shell formatting is perfect

```
sdiff -w 185 fileone filetwo
```

[image: sdiff formatting in shell is perfect]

When I use the command sdiff and send the results to a file, formatting disappears

```
sdiff -w 185 fileone filetwo > filethree
```

[image: sdiff formatting disappears when output is sent to a file]

How can I preserve formatting when I send sdiff output to a file?

Comment: does `sdiff -w 185 fileone filetwo -o output` works?

Comment: use `sdiff`'s `-t` option to expand tabs to spaces. Alternatively, tell your viewer/editor to set  tab stops to 8 spaces - e.g. in vi `:set ts=8` or with less, use `less -x8`.

Comment: @αғsнιη I'm afraid not.

Comment: @Cas This worked on the server ```sdiff -t -w 185 fileone filetwo > filethree```. When a windows webadmin opened the file, it went back to being unformatted. I added an extra command ```expand -t 2 filethree | sponge filethree``` and now the file is perfectly formatted. Hats off to you mate.

Comment: btw, `-t` should have worked for any viewer, it does exactly what `expand` does.  If you want tabstops every 2 spaces, you can use `-t --tabsize 2` with sdiff, no need for expand and sponge.

Comment: @cas Awesome. It does work with ```sdiff -t --tabsize 2 -w 185 fileone filetwo > filethree``` without the additional secondary expand | sponge command. Very nice indeed.

Comment: @cas I have and also gave you the credit. I can accept the answer tomorrow. I'll be back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by @cas, to preserve the formatting while sending `sdiff` output to a file, include `-t`

```
sdiff -t -w 185 fileone filetwo > filethree
```

To control the tabstops, include `--tabsize` along with the number of spaces

```
sdiff -t --tabsize 2 -w 185 fileone filetwo > filethree
```